# update in from multiple tables oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a table called HSN_Master with some HSN codes entered wrong.
Columns are
`HSN_Code, Description`

I have downloaded the correct Codes from GST Website and have created a Table Edited_HSN.
Columns are

```
`Old_HSN, Correct_HSN`

`HSN_Master.HSN_Code =HSN_Master.HSN_Code`
```

I wish to update HSN_Master.HSN_Code with HSN_Master.HSN_Code, where HSN_Master.Old_HSN not in Edited_HSN.Correct_HSN

What I have tried so far,

`Update Hsn_Master set  Hsn_Master.HSN_Code =Edited_HSN.Correct_HSN where Hsn_Master.HSN_Code not in (select Edited_HSN.Correct_HSN from Edited_HSN) and Hsn_Master.HSN_Code=Edited_HSN.Old_Hsn`

I am returned with error:
ORA-00904: "Edited_HSN"."OLD_HSN": invalid identifier (Edited_HSN is highlighted)

Any help in pointing out my mistake is much appreciated.

Comment: Error says that you used column name that doesn't exist. Please, post **exact** description of both tables.

Comment: @Littlefoot .... Table description as below :-

Hsn_Master Table

  Sl_No   NUMBER(14)
  HSN_Code        VARCHAR2(15 BYTE)  NOT NULL,
  NAME          VARCHAR2(70 BYTE),
  
  
Edited_HSN Table

  Old_Hsn     VARCHAR2(15 BYTE),
  OLD_NAME    VARCHAR2(255 BYTE),
  Correct_HSN   VARCHAR2(15 BYTE)

Comment: Do you really have mixed letter case? Or did you just write it like that *just because* you think it looks prettier? Because, if you do have mixed case, you'll have to enclose everything into double quotes.

Comment: @Littlefoot.... As a habit, I use mixed letter case. Code, Sql statements and Field names etc look very neat.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
Update Hsn_Master
   set Hsn_Master.HSN_Code = (select Edited_HSN.Correct_HSN
                                from Edited_HSN
                               where Hsn_Master.HSN_Code=Edited_HSN.Old_Hsn
                             )
 where Hsn_Master.HSN_Code not in (select Edited_HSN.Correct_HSN from Edited_HSN)
```

Comment: Hi @Andrew, 

Thank you for your quick response. The first sub-query '(select Edited_HSN.Correct_HSN
                                from Edited_HSN
                               where Hsn_Master.HSN_Code=Edited_HSN.Old_Hsn
                             )' returns an error ORA-00904: "Hsn_Master"."HSN_Code": invalid identifier. Maybe we didn't add 'Hsn_Master' after from.

Comment: @dandy, I cannot reproduce ORA-00904 when execute suggested query. May be you have a typo with field Hsn_Master.HSN_Code? I tried on followed script:

create table Hsn_Master (HSN_Code number(9), HSN_Name varchar2(100));
create table Edited_HSN (Correct_HSN number(9), Old_Hsn number(9));

Update Hsn_Master
   set Hsn_Master.HSN_Code = (select Edited_HSN.Correct_HSN
 from Edited_HSN where Hsn_Master.HSN_Code=Edited_HSN.Old_Hsn)
 where Hsn_Master.HSN_Code not in (select Edited_HSN.Correct_HSN from Edited_HSN);

And I got result "0 row(s) updated."

Comment: Hi @Andrew,

I'm sure I don't have a typo as I have been breaking my head over this since 4 days and have checked the query many times over.